# An alternative to sherry in trifle

Tags: wine, pairing, cooking

I want to make a proper sherry trifle, but do not want to use sherry!  Is there an alternative liqueur that won't change the whole ethos of the trifle? [Here is a link to how to make a sherry trifle.](https://www.deliaonline.com/recipes/books/delias-happy-christmas/traditional-english-trifle)

[image: picture of sherry trifle]

The liqueur I use must also be good enough to have as a drink to go with the trifle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alchermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchermes) could be a good hint, in Italy is used as an ingredient in [Zuppa inglese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuppa_Inglese), a particular derivation of trifle ...as you are trying to do.

Just a reminder, I don't think it is really good to drink it as a glass of wine, but perfect with desserts.

Comment: Now this is interesting, a big red colored tick for you!

Comment: The advice here was outstanding, alchermes was something I didn't know about.

Comment: @dougal 3.0.0 we're here for that

Comment: It's a green tick this time not a red tick - great!

Comment: Cherry Brandy, what? And you could substitute black cherry jam for the more traditional raspberry /strawberry jam ingredient.